# Writing Backwards Compatible Apps in XCode 4

Tags: xcode, macos, backwards-compatibility

I'm writing a Mac app in XCode 4 which works perfectly in Lion. However if someone tries to use it on Leopard it doesn't run and says it needs Lion. How can I make my project backwards compatible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build against the 10.5 SDK (set `[SDKROOT]` to 10.5) and set the minimum system version `[MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET]` to 10.5.

Comment: Where do I set this? initially I thought it was in the Project-Info.plist but couldn't find it in there. Having a little trouble navigating the new Xcode UI.

Comment: They are both in the build settings - you can set them at the project level so that all targets inherit the settings.